# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (512,512) (515,512)

Tags: numpy

I wan to add noise to a uniform matrix, the code I use is this:

```
import numpy as np 

s = np.random.default_rng(100).normal(10,5,512*512)

s2 = np.reshape(s, (512,512))
s2 =s2+11*np.ones((515,512))
```

It gives the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (512,512) (515,512)
```

Where is the problem here?

Comment: ... I guess it's a typo, you meant `np.ones((512,512))`? (Also it's actually useless, you can just do + 11 and it has the same effect)

Comment: I do not see the typo. I know the example is useless, but I simplifed the code to show where the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when

1. they are equal, or
2. one of them is 1

If these conditions are not met, a ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together exception is thrown, indicating that the arrays have incompatible shapes. The size of the resulting array is the size that is not 1 along each axis of the inputs.

According to that,(515, 512) & (512, 512) will successfully match at the end of the array, and will throw the error when matching 515 to 512